# How I can crop Image loaded from Gallery and Camera without Intent using by any library?

Tags: android

Which library good for crop image 
and get image from gallery and camera then crop image and set to imageview

Comment: i have done it without library and works fine

Comment: visit- http://www.appance.com/?s=crop+android

Comment: @NewCoder can you share your code on github? , the one I have make the resolution of the image bad

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/46 check this

Answer (score 0):

Try this library it work well for me in both cases - https://github.com/lvillani/android-cropimage

**Update**

It is not perfect code b'z i even got project in between so i don't get time to make it clear but you can modify and let me know. 
happy to here your comment.

```
private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 0;
private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1;
private static final int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 2;
private static final int GALLERY_KITKAT_INTENT_CALLED = 3;
private static final int CROP_IMAGE_GALLERY = 4;
private static final int CROP_IMAGE_CAMERA = 5;

private String FilePath;
private Uri ImageUri, croppedImageUri;
private File pic_file;


private void SelectImage()
{
    final CharSequence[] options = {"Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery", "Remove", "Cancel"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SignUpActivity.this);
    builder.setTitle("Upload Photo");
    builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if (options[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                pic_file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        "tmp_" + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis()) + ".jpg");
                ImageUri = Uri.fromFile(pic_file);
                cameraIntent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        ImageUri);

                cameraIntent.putExtra("return-data", true);

                startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                        android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);


            } else if (options[item].equals("Remove")) {
                ivProfilePic.setImageResource(R.mipmap.ic_profile_pic);
                FilePath = "";
                dialog.dismiss();
            } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}


/*
 * After capture Image or Select Image from Gallary  On activityResult Call
 *
 */
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {


    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        try {

           CropImage();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            rootLogger.error(Utility.createLogableFormat(Utility.getStringStackTrace(e)));
        }


    }
    else if(requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK){

        try {
            ImageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            rootLogger.error(Utility.createLogableFormat(Utility.getStringStackTrace(e)));
        }

    }
    else if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_CAMERA) {
            if (data != null) {
                // get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {
                    FilePath = ImageUri.getPath();

                    File f = new File(FilePath);

                    Bitmap bmp_post_news = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(f.getAbsolutePath(),120,120);

                    ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bmp_post_news);

                }
            }
        }
        else if (requestCode == CROP_IMAGE_GALLERY) {
            if (data != null) {
                // get the returned data
                Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

                if (extras != null) {

                    FilePath = croppedImageUri.getPath();

                    Bitmap bmp_post_news = decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(FilePath,120,120);

                    ivProfilePic.setImageBitmap(bmp_post_news);


                }

            }
        }
}

public Bitmap decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(String Filepath,
                                                  int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Filepath, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(Filepath, options);
    }

public int calculateInSampleSize(
        BitmapFactory.Options options, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    int inSampleSize = 1;
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;


    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        final int halfHeight = height / 2;
        final int halfWidth = width / 2;

        // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and keeps both
        // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
        while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
            inSampleSize *= 2;
        }
    }

    return inSampleSize;
}

protected void CropImage() {

    CropImageIntentBuilder cropImage = new CropImageIntentBuilder(3, 4,120,120, ImageUri);
    //cropImage.setOutlineColor(0xFF03A9F4);
    cropImage.setSourceImage(ImageUri);
    cropImage.setCircleCrop(true);
    cropImage.setOutlineCircleColor(Color.WHITE);
    cropImage.setOutputQuality(100);

    Intent intent = cropImage.getIntent(this);
    //intent.putExtra("return-data", false);

    startActivityForResult(intent, CROP_IMAGE_CAMERA);
}
```

Comment: Can u tell me full description code for image cropping

Comment: @KalpeshKumawat check my updated answer and accept answer if it helps.

Comment: Here.. what is "IonCircleTransform"  and  "CropImageIntentBuilder"?

Comment: tell me please about both "IonCircleTransform" and "CropImageIntentBuilder" in details

Comment: @KalpeshKumawat IonCircleTransform is my class to create image in circular form with boarder. and CropImageIntentBuilder is intent provided by library to display image.

Comment: CropImageIntentBuilder  shwoing error it telling to create class

Comment: can u give me both class CropImageIntentBuilder  and IonCircleTransform

Comment: @KalpeshKumawat CropImageIntentBuilder is in android-crop library. why u are asking just add it through gradle and you will find it. and for IonCircleTransform you can remove those line of codes and run it. it is not must things to do.

Comment: when i remove these lines then how i can get bmp_post_news ??

Comment: Thanks, it's awesome but it cropping round image not reactangle

Comment: @KalpeshKumawat remove this line  - cropImage.setCircleCrop(true);

Comment: i did add a library compile 'com.jude:imageprovider:2.0.8'
  for   "CropImageIntentBuilder "  but it creating problems like it shows china language and gallery image by default showing rounded

Comment: please tell me a library for "CropImageIntentBuilder " class

Comment: repositories {
    mavenCentral()

    maven {
        url 'http://lorenzo.villani.me/android-cropimage/'
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.soundcloud.android:android-crop:1.0.1@aar'
    compile 'me.villani.lorenzo.android:android-cropimage:1.1.+'
}

Comment: i am trying but not getting correct crop help me please

Comment: it working only in camera case not in gallery so i asked

Comment: Thank you so much.. now it working in both case Gallery and Camera..  again thanks

Comment: @KalpeshKumawat ok then accept it so it can be helpful to others.